# Whether I can use the clause as a subject

Tags: clauses, subjects

From the grammatical point of view, it is correct to use clause as a subject within sentence  ?

*I have done that task * made him upset.

*I was very tired*- made him surprised.

Comment: "**It** made him upset *that* I have done my task"

Comment: Or "That I have done that task made him upset."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to employ a clause, finite or nonfinite, as the subject of the sentence, and in this case it would be called [Subject Clause](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/function/subjclau.htm).

> That I have done that task made him upset.

Here **That I have done that task** functions as the subject clause and it is a finite clause.

Similarly, the second example contains a finite clause either, acting as the subject clause in the sentence:

> That I was very tired made him surprised.

If it were:

> To do that task made him upset.

Then a **to infinitive** clause would function as the subject clause in the sentence.

Or if it were:

> Being very tired, made him upset.

Then a **-ing** clause would function as the subject clause in the sentence.